# Data from Api is not in correct order?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http

In my app I am using a REST API to get data from a database. When I check the response from the API request in Postman, it shows one format, and when I get the response and log the data, it shows another order which is completely different than what I require.

What can be the problem? Please guide me.

Postman response:

```
{
    "testdata": {
        "attributes": {
            "year": {
                "2019": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "y": 2019,
                        "q": 1,
                    }
                ],
                "2018": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "y": 2018,
                        "q": 1,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "y": 2018,
                        "q": 4,
                    }
                ]
            },
        }
    }
}
```

myComponent.ts

```
this.testService.getdata().subscribe(d => {
    console.log(d.testdata.attributes.year);
});
```

I get this result

```
2018 Array(2)
2019 Array(1)
```

instead of

```
2019 Array(1)
2018 Array(2)
```

TestService.ts

```
getdata() {
    return this
      .http
      .get(`${environment.apiUrl}` + '/test/data');
}
```

Comment: This is not possible it seems. You will see response which api is sending.

Comment: Is there a possibility to ad a sorting order in your backend. This will always show data in the same order.

Comment: Objects are unordered. If you need to guarantee order, put them in an array.

Comment: @GuyIncognito is correct

Comment: @GuyIncognito. thanks. I will check it.